# getting a animator component in child unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a parent and child using animator. The animator in child is disabled and I want to enable it through code.

=> parent.

=>=> child

I want to get the animator component on child using this code but it is not working.

```
Anim childAnim;
childAnim = parent.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

childAnim.enabled = true;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: check that `child` is not the same as `childAnim`. Make sure that the one you get is the one you enable

Answer (score 0):

GetComponentInChildren returns the component of type in the GameObject or any of its children using depth first search. I your case its returning Animator component attached with your parent. You can use code like following

```
Animator[] childAnim;
childAnim = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>();

childAnim[1].enabled = true;
```

Its not a best practice but it will work. GetComponentsInChildren returns all the components in children and if there are multiple children index may vary. You should keep the reference of the child object which has required Animator component.

Answer (score 0):

```
Animator childAnim;
childAnim = parent.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

childAnim.enabled = true;
```

GetComponentInChildren() return the first child's Animator component (if it has), if no Animator component in first child, then you will get error.
Use `parent.find("nameofchild").GetComponent<Animator>();`